# Proving the identity $\frac{1}{\tan x}+\tan x=\frac1{\sin x\cos x}$

Tags: trigonometry, exponentiation

As I'm working on my trigonometry exercises, I come across an exercise called "prove the equality," which I proceed to solve. This all goes well, until I arrive at a certain point, after which I can't solve any further and don't understand the explanation offered in the answers section. If you would please help me understand the way of thinking needed to solve this question, I'd be very happy!

Here's the problem:

> Solve the equality:

$$\frac1{\tan(x)} + \tan(x) = \frac1{\sin(x)\cdot\cos(x)}$$

And here's what I've solved for:

$$\text{RHS}=\frac{1}{\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}} + \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)} =\frac{\cos x}{\sin x} +\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$$

Then, I get stuck. The answers section says the next step should be:

$$\frac{\cos^2(x) + \sin^2(x)}{\sin(x) \cdot \cos(x)} = \text{RHS}$$

I understand how this proves the equality, but I don't understand how they just went from the previous step to this one: where do the exponents suddenly come from??

If you would be so kind as to explain this sudden raise of powers to me... My gratitude will be infinite!

Thanks in advance
Lila

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.
For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559)
and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thanks! I'll definitely do so in the future

Comment: $$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d} = \frac{ad+bc}{bd}$$

Comment: @Kevin Thanks! Will bookmark this one for sure ;)

Comment: @Lila No problem, I presume your equality only holds for $x \neq \pi/2$ (plus the periodic zeroes thereafter). In the identity above, you cannot ever have $b, d =0$.

Comment: Did you mean two write $\frac{1}{\tan x} + \tan x = \frac{1}{\sin x} \cdot \frac{1}{\cos x}$?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig yeah that's what the original post said, I edited the title but forgot to correct the body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Way of thinking: You want to simplify the more complicated side, which is the LHS, to a less complicated expression. You have two fractions with different denominators. So you multiply the numerator and denominators of the two fractions to obtain a common denominator.$$\frac1{\tan x}+\tan x=\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}+\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}=\frac{\cos^2 x}{\cos x\sin x}+\frac{\sin^2 x}{\sin x\cos x}=\frac{\cos^2 +\sin^2x}{\sin x\cos x}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's totally clear now, I feel kind of stupid for not getting it right away...

Comment: No problem! ${}$

Answer (score 0):

We simply have

$$\frac1{\tan x}+\tan x=\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}+\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}=\frac{\cos^2 x+\sin^2 x}{\sin x\cos x}$$